# Is there a best way to detect errors after receiving a file transfer?

Tags: linux, windows, networking, ftp, scp

Is there any way to have error detection and be 100% sure that all errors will be detected at the receiver? or even while in the transfer.

CRC, checksum, hashing or ...

Comment: What methods are you using in the FTP transfer on the Windows machine? You are sending from and to with Windows on both sender and receiver side or what? Are you using command line, WinSCP, or something different?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Well, I want to see my options because I want to transfer petabytes of data and I don't like retransmissions.

Comment: Are you literally moving it or backing it up or just copying it for other reasons? You tagged `Windows` in your question so is that the sender or receiver side or one or both or are you saying you want suggestion for either on either side?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT I want to move petabytes of data every day (100Gbps it usually takes 23H) (it is sensors data) and it doesn't matter I can switch to Linux or... I want to make sure that I received the data correctly because the data is very large I want something to tell me the data is correct like 100%. somebody told me you should do zip and at the reciver do unzip but im not sure it would be 100% foolproof

Comment: One problem you have is that unless this in built in the transfer application, you are going to double the read bandwidth at the source and add a read step at the target. This can significantly slow down the transfer. There are specialized protocols to transfer very large files, they will take care of this and also optimize bandwidth usage (regular protocols waste a lot of bandwidth).

Comment: @xenoid thank you, I would appreciate if you could name some of the protocols. 1 last question I want to do this inside network instead of end host to spread the calculation costs.

Comment: I've seen Aspera used by a large TV channel (several petabytes/year of broadcast-grade digital videos).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of those methods you listed will work (hashing, CRC, checksums).  They are also very reliable.  CRC and checksums are typically used during the transfer and are not seen, unless there is an error.  You would do a hash check before and after the transfer.  Obviously, a file that differs even by 1 bit, would have a different hash.

Are they 100% foolproof?  No.  However, they are pretty much as close as you can get without doing a bit by bit binary comparison.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Is there any way to calculate detection error probability?

Comment: @Arash I dont know.  How often does memory experience bit flip?  There are whitepapers on that.  However, computers and networks have methods that should hopefully detect and correct the error.